# Route from URL with parameters to my PWA in iOS and Android instead of opening in browser

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, routes, progressive-web-apps

I have links we will be sending out the users to install the PWA and open it in the app with parameters.  Currently, when they click on the URL (if they have to app installed or not) it directs them to the browser and NOT the app.  I think I might need to update the manifest, but I'm not sure where to target or send them so it opens in the app instead.  This is my first PWA, and it's going well except this issue.  This is a mobile app with React.

Answer (score -1):

you should look about deep-link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_linking

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).